# How do I change the start up sound?

Tags: startup, music, customization, desktop-background

How do i change the start up background music in Ubuntu and can i add any customized music for startup? What are the various ways of setting this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want another sound during login you can do it this way from a terminal sesson:

```
cd /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo
```

replace the file

```
desktop-login.ogg
```

with the soundfile you want. You can do it like this (including backup):

```
sudo cp desktop-login.ogg desktop-login.ogg.old
sudo cp ~/Downloads/dekstop-login.ogg .
```

if your new file is inside your home's Download directory.
I have not seen a default application where you can do this.

And yes, you can create a custom sound from for instance a music clip with `audacity`. Just make sure you save it as `ogg` and do not make it too long.

---

You can also do it like this. From commandline

```
gksu nautilus
```

This will open Nautilus as root. Now navigate to your new file, rightclick and `copy` it. Navigate to `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` and click on `desktop-login.ogg`, press F2, and add .old to the name. Then click on some free space, rightclick and choose `paste`

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are referring to the sound file here:

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg
```

Which is a symbolic link to:

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/dialog-question.ogg
```

You could simply backup these files and replace with your own files.

Answer (score 2):

/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg is a symbolic link to dialog-question.ogg. Therefore, remove the symbolic link and copy the sound you want to system-ready.ogg:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg

sudo cp myfunkysound.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg
```

To restore the original conditions after doing the above, do this:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg

cd /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/

ln -s dialog-question.ogg system-ready.ogg
```