# How can I play different sounds each time I startup?

Tags: sound, login, startup

I have read questions on [Changing startup sound in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138760/changing-start-up-sound-in-ubuntu) and [Changing startup music in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556960).

I understand how to rename 'desktop-login.ogg' and copy the sound I want as 'desktop-login.ogg'.

My question is -is there a way I can play *different* sounds (i.e. choose a random file from a set of files in a defined music folder) each time I login?
It may sound silly, but if possible I would like to play different sounds.

I am guessing that this may be perhaps possible by running some kind of script which replaces/renames the desktop-login.ogg file each time I shutdown, so that a new file is ready to be played on the next startup.  But I don't know how to copy a new file from a particular folder to desktop-login.ogg upon each shutdown, nor do I know where the script should reside.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to do it, or if there is an easier way of doing this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a music file to play from a defined folder of files, this is one way to go (open a terminal to execute the commands):

1. **Choose the music player**:
   I am suggesting **vlc** but other choices like **mplayer** also work. If you have only ogg files **canberra-gtk-play** or **paplay** is fine.
   Playback check:
   `cvlc --play-and-exit path/to/Music/song.ext`
   `mplayer path/to/Music/song.ext`
   `paplay path/to/Music/song.ext`
   `canberra-gtk-play -f path/to/Music/song.ext`
2. **Create a new script**:
   `sudo gedit /usr/bin/play_rand_login.sh`
   and paste the following:
   `#!/bin/bash`
   `files=(/home/me/Music/*)`
   `cvlc --play-and-exit "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"`
   Change the music path `/home/me/Music` to your actual folder.
   Replace cvlc with your player choice and close the file.
   Now make the file executable:
   `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/play_rand_login.sh`
3. **Open** the *Startup Applications Preferences*, choose the **Gnome login sound** and edit the command to read:
   `/usr/bin/play_rand_login.sh`
4. **Logout and login** to test if all is well.

**Notes**:

- It is not guaranteed to have a different file playing at two subsequent logins but if you have many files the chances are high.
- Tested to work at on Ubuntu 12.04 (using Gnome 3).
- The bash random file choice is coming from a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701505/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory-in-a-shell-script).

Comment: thank you very much for providing detailed instructions.  I appreciate it.  I will try it out as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **canberra-gtk-play** to play audio file at startup.

Command to run Canberra-gtk-play `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play -f <file_name.ogg>`

You **Startup Applications** to play this during Ubuntu start up.
Name: Startup Sound
command: /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play -f file_name.ogg
Comment: Some comment

Comment: thank you for your response and informing me about the application  Canberra-gtk-play.  I will try it out.  Sorry, I was not clear in my post above that I am looking for a way to automatically change the filename and play a different file after each startup.

Comment: I think your question is clear enough. But to be more precise I think you could say "choose a random file from a set of files in a defined music folder".

Comment: @rosch, thank you for your suggestion.  I will modify my question.