# How can I play radio stream as my startup (login screen) sound?

Tags: sound, startup, streaming

I am familiar with [How do I change the start up sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138760/how-do-i-change-the-start-up-sound) and [Chainging startup music of Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556960), so I know how to change my startup sound to `.ogg` file of my choosing, but...

How to change it to some online radio stream?

So, as long as I do not log in, the steam is played. Since it's a stream, it will never end (unless I log in, turn of the computer or disconnect from internet).

Is that even possible?

> NOTE: I am useing Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin

Comment: you could try to create an ogg vorbis live-stream, which you set as your startup sound. Don't ask me how to do it...

Comment: You can probably do something using a pipe - have a program connect to the radio stream and output to a named pipe (instead of your audio device). Then connect to that named pipe with your audio player, or in this case, the start-up sound playing code.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure I know what you both mean, it'll require some googleing on my part, but thanks for suggestions, I'll study them!