# How to change Ubuntu 14.04 drum beat tone?

Tags: 14.04

I want to change the drum beat tone in my Ubuntu 14.04 and replace it with a new one. So I downloaded a new tone. I searched in Google to do this and I tried 4-5 links I found. But nothing happened, the drum is still beating. Actually is the drum beat start up tone or system ready tone ?

Can anyone tell the correct procedures to change the drum beat tone in 14.04 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The drum beat tone is actually system ready tone.

- So I went to /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo and renamed "system-ready.ogg" to "system-ready.ogg.old" and copied new sound file.
- The new sound file should have the name "system-ready.ogg".

During the next start up the new sound will be heard instead of drum beat.

Comment: This is really the fastest way.

Comment: Hi guys, I have tried above. It disables drum beat sound but not playing my new sound ... I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score -1):

Check this thread: [How do I change startup sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138760/how-do-i-change-the-start-up-sound). The steps are already posted.

If you are looking for new audio files, you can check these links.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/sam-hulick-ubuntu-start-sound

Comment: I already tried that and it was unsuccessful.

Comment: I checked my 'stereo' directory after executing the following commands -                                                       "sudo cp desktop-login.ogg desktop-login.ogg.old",
"sudo cp ~/Downloads/dekstop-login.ogg . "                             The new sound file is there. But when I starts my system, the drum beat is playing instead of the new one. Why ?