# How to replace default notify sound (drum roll) when logon and shutdown PC with custom sound?

Tags: 14.04, sound, desktop-environments

Ubuntu 14.04: how to replace default drum roll sound when login dialogue and shutdown PC  with custom sound? Should I just rename these files and place instead of it my custom .ogg file with the same name?

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg

/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg
```

Comment: Yes, but your question is probably a duplicate, please see, http://askubuntu.com/questions/138760/how-do-i-change-the-start-up-sound

Comment: I my case, system-ready.ogg is "link to audio" (Link target: Dialog-question.ogg) - how to rename it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

system-ready.ogg is just a symlink to dialog-question.ogg

desktop-login.ogg is an actual file

Personally, in your case:

A) I’d add the .ogg file(s) you want played to that directory.

B) Copy desktop-login.ogg to desktop-login-orig.ogg (and any others you want to replace).

C) Make symlinks from system-ready.ogg and desktop-login.ogg to the files you want played (and any others).

But this is no real difference than what is written on the other question...